# How do browsers deal with abandoned/destroyed page elements containing inline event handlers

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events, browser-cache

Using plain vanilla JavaScript, lets say I have a container DIV that starts empty, such as...

```
<DIV id='myID'></DIV>
```

Then I add one or more new DIV elements to the container, which have one or more inline handlers, like so...

```
var myDIV = document.getElementById('myID') 
myDIV.innerHTML = "<div  onmouseover=\"hoverme(this);\">TEXT</DIV>";
```

Now let's say I later empty the container like so...

```
myDIV.innerHTML = "";
```

Now assume that:

1. More than one such DIV with one or more inline events may have been included in the 'innerHTML' string,
2. These event(s) may or may not have been triggered and/or dealt with prior to the container being set to "".
3. After the container is "cleared" this way, it is likely that another string containing one or more DIVs with inline events will again be added to the container.

My questions are to understand whether there is a negative impact on the browser if the above is repeated multiple times before the page is exited. For example...

1. Are the elements that were added to the original container "destroyed" (along with their event) by setting the containers inner HTML to "", or are they actually just 'abandoned" but still present in the browser internally?
2. In the latter case, would the browser's internal management of events also suffer over time?
3. Also in the latter case, is there a simple change I can make (such as setting the container's innerHTML to null) which would result in my hoped for "automatic garbage collection"?
4. If the longevity of this ongoing process matters, let me point out that it will be short. Since the above is part of a navigation panel, its purpose is to allow a visitor to browse and select a different page to go to. So can I at least assume any "ill effects" on the browser will be "flushed" after the navigation to a new page is complete.

NOTE: I realize the use of addEventListener() is generally considered better than inline events, and that using "removeEventListener() on all added handlers looks technically cleaner. But the question would remain, as to whether the removal was necessary, if the original container of all items containing event handlers were 'flushed' or set to 'null'. So again, would the events automatically be removed from the browsers workflow?

Comment: The elements, and the event handlers installed on them (whether through inline attributes or proper DOM methods), are subject to normal garbage collection. They will be destroyed if nothing refers to them any more.

Comment: Hoping this is true, yet asked because I couldn't prove it on any of the excellent MDN references. Indeed, it was the reason i thought 'inline' handlers would mean less code, since I wouldn't have to worry about removing them. But it does beg the question whether removeEventHandler() is even needed in half the cases I HAVE done so.

Comment: No, calling  `remveEventHandler` on elements before removing them is unnecessary as well. Decades ago, internet explorer had some bugs there, so you might find old advice still recommending it.